# Probability of a set having no elements removed when randomly removing elements from *m* sets

Tags: probability, statistics

I have *n* elements uniformly distributed over *m* sets, if I were to randomly remove *x* elements, what’s the number of sets *y* that have no elements removed. Specifically, what’s the relationship between *x* and *y*.

It is safe to assume that *n* is much greater than *m*.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “uniformly distributed over $m$ sets”?  Is it just $m$ disjoint sets each containing exactly $n/m$ elements?

Comment: Yes @erick-wong, it's *m* disjoint sets containing exactly *n/m* elements

Comment: Thanks, I think the use of “uniformly distributed” made it sound like a random process rather than just evenly divided.

Comment: It is a pseudo-random process (fill one set, and then the next and so on), but each set is capped to the same number of elements.

Comment: Would you agree that, for the purposes of this question, it might as well just be the integer ranges $[1,n/m]$, $[n/m+1, 2n/m]$, and so on?  Just by relabeling.

Comment: Yes, that's a fair way to represent it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that the $x$ elements are selected without replacement, uniformly from the pool of $n$ elements.  Alternative interpretations would be selection with replacement (which simplifies the analysis), or selection of a random element of a random set, which is initially simple but also gets complicated when $x$ is large enough to eliminate an entire set).

Fix a particular target set $S$ and we compute the probability that all of its elements survive each of the $x$ removals.  In the first removal, there are $n$ elements and $n/m$ in $S$, so the probability of hitting $S$ is $1/m$.  On the second removal, conditionally on $S$ being untouched, there are $n-1$ elements and $n/m$ in $S$, so the probability of hitting $S$ is $n/((n-1)m)$.

In general, the conditional probability of $S$ surviving the $k$th removal intact is $1 - n/((n-k+1)m)$, so the probability of surviving all removals is:

$$\prod_{k=1}^x \bigg( 1 - \frac{n}{m(n-k+1)}\bigg).$$

By linearity of expectation, the expected value of $y$ is just $m$ times the above product.  Note that the product becomes identically zero when $x > n-n/m$, which is expected.  For $x$ very small compared to $n/m$, we can approximate $n-k+1$ with $n$ to simplify this to $\approx m ( 1 - 1/m )^x \approx m \exp(-x/m)$.  This also holds for large $x$ in the case that we draw with replacement.